# How to highlighting a specific row in html table

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html table where I am showing product wise sales and it subtotals. Desired output Sample given below:

[image]

html code for the same as below:

```
<body>
    
    <form>
          <label style="font-size:20; font-weight:bold; text-align:center"> Sales </label>
    </form>
    
    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border="1" cellspacing=0>
    
    <tr bgcolor="#151A7B"  style="color:white;">
        <th> Product </th>
        <th> Units </th>
        <th> Sales </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> %% Product %% </td>
        <td> %% Units %% </td>
        <td> %% Sales %% </td>
    </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to highlight the subtotal row. Is it possible to do so using simple html? As I am embedding this report to outlook mail body.

Comment: For starters get in the practice of closing your tags, missing the table close tab.

Comment: You can use inline-styling or `nth-child()` CSS selector. Check my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS `:nth-child()` [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

```css
.mytable tr:nth-child(3),
.mytable tr:nth-child(5) {
  color: white;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable" style="border-collapse:collapse;" border="1" cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <th> Product </th>
    <th> Units </th>
    <th> Sales </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> %% Product %% </td>
    <td> %% Units %% </td>
    <td> %% Sales %% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Subtotal </td>
    <td> xxx </td>
    <td> xxx </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> %% Product %% </td>
    <td> %% Units %% </td>
    <td> %% Sales %% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Subtotal </td>
    <td> xxx </td>
    <td> xxx </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or if you want, you can use [inline-styling](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp):

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border="1" cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <th> Product </th>
    <th> Units </th>
    <th> Sales </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> %% Product %% </td>
    <td> %% Units %% </td>
    <td> %% Sales %% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:orange;color:white;">
    <td> Subtotal </td>
    <td> xxx </td>
    <td> xxx </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In your first code, this only applied to the last 'tr'.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi yes, OP wants to highlight subtotal row which is the last row in his table.

Comment: But based on his image, there are multiple 'subtotal'!!!

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Yes you are right, I didn't really saw the other subtotals. Editing my answer.

Comment: Yes, now it works. But if the table is long, and would have existed several 'subtotal', this will be duplicated. There had to be a better way.

Comment: I cannot static code subtotal tag. is there any dynamic way to highlight the row ? I havent tried the css method though

Comment: @Aditya_Chitale if you can use javascript, then you can do many things "dynamic", even though I can't really understand why you can't use plain CSS. In any case, with javascript, you can check for the string "subtotal" and highlight the entire row.

Comment: @GeorgeChond style tag does not work when I try to embedd this table in outlook. Thanks though. It worked using inline css method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need CSS for that you last child selector or simply create a class for specific table you want to highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use from a class attribute for the desired '**tr**'s:

```css
/* CSS */

.sub{
  background-color: salmon;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border="1" cellspacing=0>
    
    <tr bgcolor="#151A7B"  style="color:white;">
        <th> Product </th>
        <th> Units </th>
        <th> Sales </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> A </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub">
        <td> subtotal </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> B </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> C </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub">
        <td> subtotal </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> D </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> E </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> F </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub">
        <td> subtotal </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: The table in my case here is dynamic. I dont want to create separate rows manually using <tr> tags as the number of entries will keep on increasing everyday. Also I cant use the nth child method as the position of subtotal will change if number of entries increase. Is there any dynamic method for colouring the subtotal row while still maintaining its position dynamically in the table ?

Comment: @Aditya_Chitale. In this case, I think you must use javascript. although you tell worked inline CSS.